# Does maven artifact inherit from the parent pom of a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven artifact (`Artifact A`) which depends on a certain artifact (`Artifact B`).

`Artifact B` has a parent pom where certain another dependencies are included.

Can `artifact A` use these dependencies, without explicitly adding them under dependencies section of its own pom?

Comment: You can make B as a parent of A or use the parent.pm for A too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `B`'s parent pom *will not* be a parent pom of `A`, dependencies defined in `B`'s parent pom are considered `B`'s dependencies. Since dependencies are transitive (in compile / default scope anyway), `A` will depend on the dependencies defined in `B`'s parent pom. So you can use them.

I would argue however that `A` should in most cases still explicitly define the dependencies it is using in it's pom instead of relying on them being transitive dependencies of `B` - that should be considered an implementation detail. `A` should not break if `B` drops some of its dependencies because it doesn't need them anymore.